# How to highlight Finder items when going back from a nested folder

Tags: macos, finder

I would like to know how to setup highlighting the item of Finder even when I go back from a nested folder. It's when I display folders in list view.

This is the current status: after I open "01_core_edit" folder and click the back button, there is no highlighted item in Finder as follows:

[image: Current status]

What I would like  to have  when I click back is shown below:

[image: Expected view]

If I had that setting, I could easily find the selected item when going back and it'd be much easier to operate. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found how to do this by command but not by back button.

<kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>↑</kbd>

Answer (score 1):

This is not exactly what you are looking for, but I'm not sure if what you are asking is possible. If you select Finder option `Always open folders in a new window` then the original window with the highlighted folder will be preserved.

Go to `Finder - Preferences` to change this setting.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for telling me and My setting is like it. I should put more information about my Finder view type. Sorry about it. when to use column view, I can see the selected item is highlighted. But I would like to see selected item by highlighting in the list view.